# accessing Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

may be a simple issue but cannot seem to solve it after some searching as well :) .. The scenario is as follows:

Using PhoneGap, am receiving a json object via Ajax using jquery. the object needs to be displayed on a next screen (first is the Search page and the next is the Search result page).

when the object is received, it is being saved in the sessionStorage variable (e.g. sessionStorage.result = data).

but when it is tried to be accessed on the next page, it gives an error saying that the property is unknown. e.g.

```
var result = sessionStorage.result;

alert(result.response.businesses[0].name);
```

have also tried:

```
alert($(result.response.businesses[0].name));
```

it says that the property is unknow. the basic structure of the json is as follows:

```
{
  "action": "SearchBusiness",
  "meta": {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "OK"
  },
  "response": {
    "searchQuery": {
      "categoryId": 4,
      "communityId": 4,
      "latitude": "",
      "longitude": "",
      "category": "Grocery Stores",
      "community": "Indian/Pakistani",
      "searchRadius": "",
      "city": "",
      "postalCode": ""
    },
    "businesses": [
      {
"businessId": "2",
        "name": "Name",
        "address": "123",
        "phone": "(123) 456 7890",
        "city": "any city",
        "country": "United States",
        "state": "Abc",
        "postalCode": "a123",
        "url": "",
        "logoUrl": null,
        "latitude": "0.1951704",
        "longitude": "-1.89512",
        "categoryId": "4",
        "communityId": "4",
        "ratings": "0",
        "ratingAvg": "0.00",
        "distance": 0
      }
]
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if your browser supports sessionStorage?

Comment: yes.. issue solved by using JSON.parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrongly accessing that value,

Try,

```
var result = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.result);    
alert($(result.businesses[0].name));
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. its gives a similar error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: @AbdulAli Just parse it before accessing its values.

Answer (score 0):

in your json codes missing }  your codes must be like that

```
{
    "action": "SearchBusiness",
    "meta": {
        "code": 200,
        "message": "OK"
    },
    "response": {
        "searchQuery": {
            "categoryId": 4,
            "communityId": 4,
            "latitude": "",
            "longitude": "",
            "category": "Grocery Stores",
            "community": "Indian/Pakistani",
            "searchRadius": "",
            "city": "",
            "postalCode": ""
        },
        "businesses": [{
            "businessId": "2",
            "name": "Name",
            "address": "123",
            "phone": "(123) 456 7890",
            "city": "any city",
            "country": "United States",
            "state": "Abc",
            "postalCode": "a123",
            "url": "",
            "logoUrl": null,
            "latitude": "0.1951704",
            "longitude": "-1.89512",
            "categoryId": "4",
            "communityId": "4",
            "ratings": "0",
            "ratingAvg": "0.00",
            "distance": 0
        }]
    }
}
```

alert(result.response.businesses[0].name); // it will work i think. no error
also look sessionstroge is there any data

Answer (score 0):

Your Json string is not a valid JSON format  plz check the format

```
{
"action": "SearchBusiness",
"meta": {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "OK"
},
"response": {
    "searchQuery": {
        "categoryId": 4,
        "communityId": 4,
        "latitude": "",
        "longitude": "",
        "category": "Grocery Stores",
        "community": "Indian/Pakistani",
        "searchRadius": "",
        "city": "",
        "postalCode": ""
    },
    "businesses": [{
        "businessId": "2",
        "name": "Name",
        "address": "123",
        "phone": "(123) 456 7890",
        "city": "any city",
        "country": "United States",
        "state": "Abc",
        "postalCode": "a123",
        "url": "",
        "logoUrl": null,
        "latitude": "0.1951704",
        "longitude": "-1.89512",
        "categoryId": "4",
        "communityId": "4",
        "ratings": "0",
        "ratingAvg": "0.00",
        "distance": 0
    }]
}
```

}

Comment: json was copied from a long list. may have missed some brackets. :) . Answer has been found .. thank you. have used JSON.stringify when saving the variable and JSON.parse when accessing it